# Connecting a task done by user A to user B (Android - kotlin)

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

Does anyone knows how can i connect a task done by user A to user B? For example, user A has asked user B to accept or decline a task that has been done by user A.

Here's a code that I've done for both user A and B:

```
action_done.setOnClickListener {
     request.close(uid, STATUS_CLOSED, STATUS_CODE_BY_REGULAR
                     status_message.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {
                        if (it.isSuccessful) {
                            setResult(RESULT_OK)
                            finish()
                        } else
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to close request"
                                    , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
```